# How to make failover rdbms with multiply datasources

Tags: java, jboss, teiid

We have two data sources
1. Excel file
2. Postgress db table
Need to make failover as "if db is down get data from excel, but get the data concurrent to speed up". It is possible to make this failover over vdb in teiid?

Answer (score 0):

No, not currently. But it is an interesting use case. I can see as failover with some access preference levels.

This falls into Teiid's multi-source feature [1], which would need some enhancements to work as you described. Right now if the client is aware that if the source is not available then it can proactively switch the queries, but to make Teiid decide needs some work.

[1] http://teiid.github.io/teiid-documents/master/content/reference/r_multisource-models.html

Answer (score 0):

Logged https://issues.redhat.com/browse/TEIID-5925 to capture this as a materialization enhancement.